# How to create CSS timeline with different colors

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a timeline that has a different colored line based on a given status.

This is nearly identical to what I'm trying to do:

[image]

What I've tried:

```css
.my-timeline ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.my-timeline li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.my-timeline li:before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #b8b8b8;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
    width: 3px;
}

.my-timeline li.isComplete:before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #008000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
    width: 3px;
}

.my-timeline li:after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #b8b8b8;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}

.my-timeline li.isComplete:after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #008000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-timeline">
    <ol>
        <li class="isComplete">
            fdssdfdsfs
        </li>
        <li class="">Item 2</li>
        <li class="">
            <div>Helo world</div>
        </li>
        <li class="">Item 4</li>
        <li class="">Item 5</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

The only problem with my attempt is that if I want to use anything other than just text in the `<li>` element, it will not format well.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: "*...if I want to use anything other than just text in the `<li>` element, it will not format well.*" - what other content would you like to add to the `<li>` elements, and how would you like it to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would swap around your `::before` and `::after`. Use `::before` to do the circles and `::after` to do the lines. This keeps the circle next to the top of the `<li>`, where we want it.

To tidy up, we want the line `::after` to go green only if the **next** element `.isComplete`, and then we want to hide the line `::after` the last element.

(Note that CSS distinguishes between [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) and [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements). `::before` and `::after` are pseudo-elements, so you should denote them with a double colon.)

```css
.my-timeline ol, .my-better-timeline ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.my-timeline li, .my-better-timeline li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.my-timeline li::before, .my-better-timeline li::after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #b8b8b8;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
    width: 3px;
}

/* start the line below the circle, avoids a grey line going through a green circle */
.my-better-timeline li::after {
    top: 15px;
}

.my-timeline li.isComplete::before,
/* only make the line green if the NEXT element is complete */
.my-better-timeline li:has(+li.isComplete)::after {
    background-color: #008000;
}

.my-timeline li::after, .my-better-timeline li::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #b8b8b8;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}

.my-timeline li.isComplete::after, .my-better-timeline li.isComplete::before {
    background-color: #008000;
}

/* don't display a line after the final circle */
.my-better-timeline li:last-child::after {
    display: none;    
}
```

```html
<h1>Improved</h1>
<div class="my-better-timeline">
    <ol>
        <li class="isComplete">Item 1</li>
        <li class="isComplete">Item 2</li>
        <li class="isComplete">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec semper ut augue et consectetur. Vestibulum convallis consequat nulla lacinia ultrices. Nulla non metus dolor. Aenean ultrices odio id sem commodo mattis. Sed ut tempor enim. Suspendisse sit amet dictum leo, et congue mauris. Nulla sit amet iaculis lorem. Nullam auctor lacus eu sapien tristique ornare.</div>
        </li>
        <li class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec semper ut augue et consectetur. Vestibulum convallis consequat nulla lacinia ultrices. Nulla non metus dolor. Aenean ultrices odio id sem commodo mattis. Sed ut tempor enim. Suspendisse sit amet dictum leo, et congue mauris. Nulla sit amet iaculis lorem. Nullam auctor lacus eu sapien tristique ornare.</li>
        <li class="">Item 5</li>
    </ol>
</div>

<h1>Original</h1>
<div class="my-timeline">
    <ol>
        <li class="isComplete">
            fdssdfdsfs
        </li>
        <li class="">Item 2</li>
        <li class="">
            <div>Helo world</div>
        </li>
        <li class="">Item 4</li>
        <li class="">Item 5</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```